# Selenium Web-driver Passing in parameters from Excel Sheet

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am passing in parameters from excel sheet using TestNg dataprovider and Apache POI api.

The trouble I am having is passing in a numeric value. My code:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "RegisterPage")
public void registerPage(String foreName, String surName, int dateOfBirth, String addressLine1, String addressLine2, String addressLine3, String City, 
        String County, String postCode, String nationalInsuranceNO, int telephoneNo, String userName, String confirmUsername, String password,
        String confirmPassword, String memorableWord){
```

The error I get from console is: Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell

ExcelUtils Class File Code:

```
package testNG;
//Excel Function to open, read and write parameters/values from an Excel Document to class files or tests. 
        import java.io.FileInputStream;

        import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

        import java.io.FileOutputStream;

        import java.io.IOException;

        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;

        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;

        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;

        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

    public class ExcelUtils {

            private static XSSFSheet ExcelWSheet;

            private static XSSFWorkbook ExcelWBook;

            private static XSSFCell Cell;

            private static XSSFRow Row;

        public static Object[][] getTableArray(String FilePath, String SheetName) throws Exception {   

           String[][] tabArray = null;

           try {

               FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream("C://Selenium-java-maven//workSpace//SeleniumWebDriver-TestNG//src//regData//RegisterOLPTestData.xlsx");

               // Access the required test data sheet

               ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);

               ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);

               int startRow = 1; // Starts from row 1 in Excel not row 0

               int startCol = 1; // Starts from Columns 1 in Excel not row 0

               int ci,cj;

               int totalRows = ExcelWSheet.getLastRowNum();

               // you can write a function as well to get Column count

               int totalCols = 3; //Total Sheet columns 

               tabArray=new String[totalRows][totalCols];

               ci=0;

               for (int i=startRow;i<=totalRows;i++, ci++) {               

                  cj=0;

                   for (int j=startCol;j<=totalCols;j++, cj++){

                       tabArray[ci][cj]=getCellData(i,j);

                       System.out.println(tabArray[ci][cj]);  

                        }

                    }

                }

            catch (FileNotFoundException e){

                System.out.println("Could not read the Excel sheet");

                e.printStackTrace();

                }

            catch (IOException e){

                System.out.println("Could not read the Excel sheet");

                e.printStackTrace();

                }

            return(tabArray);

            }

        public static String getCellData(int RowNum, int ColNum) throws Exception {

            try{

                Cell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum);

                int dataType = Cell.getCellType();

                if  (dataType == 3) {

                    return "";

                }else{

                    String CellData = Cell.getStringCellValue();

                    return CellData;

                }}catch (Exception e){

                System.out.println(e.getMessage());

                throw (e);

                }

            }

    }
```

Comment: Which is the row where you experience this issue?

Comment: @Lajos Arpad, I only have 2 rows. The first row is just titles, however, I start from row 1 so row 0 which is the titles isn't counted. So only row 1. 1 row 16 cols.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you try to pass a `String` as an `int`. If you have a method, which expects an integer, but you pass a `String`, then you will receive this error. You either change the type of the parameter, overload the method or pass `Integer.parseInt(foo)` instead of `foo`.

EDIT:

Finally got more information about the problem. The problem is that the parameter `dateOfBirth` is int and a `String` is passed. The simple solution would be to change the type of `dateOfBirth` to `String`, so there will be no type conflict at the end. Depending on the needs, it might be better to use a `class` designed specifically for this purpose, like [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), both in the method and at the place where the method is called.

Comment: So I would have for example Integer.parseInt("29/03/1995") ? instead of int dateOfBirth? Also would using XML to store parameters be better practice than using excel? @Lajos Arpad

Comment: @Speedychuck, since you finally gave more details about the problem, we know that dateOfBirth is not passed as an int. It is passed as a date, represented as a String. You either change the parameter type to String, or both the type and the variable to be passed to a Date type. The latter is more elegant.